# why my environment didn't change when i changed it in compose file?

Tags: postgresql, docker-compose, dockerfile, pgadmin

i ran postgres database with docker compose, but when i change environment in compose file, my login username and password didn't work, for example if i change environments in compose `PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIl` but can not login with new data

here is my compose file:

```
version: '3'

services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: example_password
      POSTGRES_USER: example_user
      POSTGRES_DB: example_db

  pgadmin:
    image: dpage/pgadmin4
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    environment:
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL: example_email@example.com
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD: example_password
    links:
      - db:pgsql-server
```

i dont know why this is happening.

do you know why this issue happen?

i tried to restart my container with `docker-compose down` and `docker compose up -d` but my problem didn't solve.

Comment: Please post the exact complete error message as text - **no images**.

Comment: I typically set an environment variable with the syntax `- POSTGRES_PASSWORD=example_password`  I'm not sure if your syntax is equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

[From the docs](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres):

> #### Environment Variables
>
> ...
>
> **Warning**: the Docker specific variables will only have an effect if you start the container with a data directory that is empty; any pre-existing database will be left untouched on container startup.

In other words, your environment variables are read and used only the first time you start the container, when a new empty database is created.  Changing variables later when the database already exists has no effect - unless you delete the volume and start clean again.